# Need to use a razor view stored in another folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In order to access a razor view in a folder other than the standard one (MVC 5 VS 2013) I found out (in this forum) two solutions: add the web config in that folder or add the following  at the top of the view: "@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"
I tried both approaches and it works, but the view, however, is displayed by itself, alone, without the _layout, the menu, nav bar, etc... 
I'm wondering if is it possible to display the view as part of the app framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout path must be specified in the view. The alternative, and what exists by default in the `Views` folder is to use a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file to set the layout, and then any view in that folder or a nested folder will use that layout unless told otherwise.

The easiest solution then, is to just specify the layout in your view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/path/to/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Or, you can create `_ViewStart.cshtml` in your other views folder and add the above code there. Not sure if that will actually work with a non-standard views folder, though, but you're welcome to try it.

Comment: I choose the "easiest solution" though case it worked right away and I'm totally in favor of DRY  (Don't repeat yourself) Actually, that is why I need a different folder where I can put custom views for different customer's requirements